# Merging data from 2 different files based on 2 columns matching

Tags: microsoft-excel

I see several situations and answers on this site that are interesting but I am not confident in what approach is best. I have two spreadsheets with column A containing first names and B last names. Spreadsheet 1 has a demographic list and 2 has insurance policies and group numbers and company names. Spreadsheet 1 has names not on 2 and vice versa. I only want to add data from 2 if the first and last name is on the same row of 1.

So if Sheet 2 has a first name and last name located in A2 and B2 match the same combination in column 1 and 2 in Sheet 1, I want to add the data from Sheet 2 found in C2, D2, and E2 to the row where that first name and last name was found.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in several ways.

You could use Power Query to get the two sheets of data, then do a merge with the first and the last name columns as the two key fields. This can all be done by clicking icons on ribbons. No code needs to be written.

Or you can use a formula approach. Again, there are different ways of doing this:

- create a helper column with a formula that combines first and last name `=A1 & " " & B1` or something along these lines, then use XLookup() to pull the values from sheet 2, based on a found value in the helper column
- If you don't have XLookup, you can use a more complex Index/Match formula that combines the first and last name in the Match() function.

I suggest you try the helper column/Xlookup approach first. It might be easiest to understand and adjust. Xlookup() is well documented in Microsoft pages and multiple blog posts.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this array (CSE) formula in Sheet1, Cell H12, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill across.

  ```
  {=IF(ISBLANK(H$11),"",IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!H$21:H$26,MATCH($F12&$G12,Sheet2!$F$21:$F$26&Sheet2!$G$21:$G$26,0)),""))}
  ```
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*